# Does there exist a fibre preserving diffeomorphism from $T S^1$ onto $S^1 \times \mathbb R\ $?

Tags: differential-geometry, diffeomorphism

> Does there exist a fibre preserving diffeomorphism $\phi : TS^1 \longrightarrow S^1 \times \mathbb R\ $?

(Here $TS^1$ denotes the tangent bundle of $S^1$)

Any help would be warmly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it exists. Taking the angular coordinate $\theta$ gives you a globally defined vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$ on $S^1$ (even though the coordinate function itself is defined up to a point).

Any tangent vector $v$ at $p\in S^1$ is proportional to this vector field at $p$, $v=v^\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}|_p$. The isomorphism you are looking for is

$$
(p,v_p)\in TM \mapsto (p,v_p^\theta)\in S^1\times\mathbb{R}
$$

There are other ways of seeing that $S^1$ has trivial tangent bundle (in the jargon, $S^1$ is parallelizable). $S^1$ is a Lie group, and the tangent bundle of every $m$-dimensional Lie group is isomorphic to $G\times \mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: Is $v_p^{\theta}$ the angle that $v_p$ makes with the positive direction of $x$-axis?

Comment: No, it is not. $v_p^\theta$ is the component of the tangent vector with respect to the basis $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\}$ of $T_p S^1$. 

With this picture of having $S^1$ inside $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the standard circle of radius 1, it is the orthogonal projection of $v$ along the line $T_p M$, oriented by the $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$.